# iOS UITableViewCell CornerRadius Constant

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am extending UITableView and overriding setBackgroundView to add a gradient to cell in a grouped style table view. All good so far...

In order to apply rounded corners to the cell, I set the cornerRadius to 10 which looks about right.

All is working well but I don't like the idea of hardcoding the cornerRadius. Is this constant somewhere in the Cocoa code base?

Example:

```
- (void) setBackgroundView:(UIView *)backgroundView{
  NSLog(@"called setBackground");

  NSLog(@"%f", backgroundView.layer.shadowRadius); //yields 0.00000
  NSLog(@"%f", backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius); //yields 3.00000

  CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  [gradient setCornerRadius:10];
  [gradient setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [gradient setBorderWidth:0.8f];
  [gradient setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
  gradient.frame = backgroundView.bounds;
  gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], (id)  [[UIColor colorWithRed:.05 green:.65 blue:.05 alpha:1] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.05 green:.65 blue:.05 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.05 green:.45 blue:.05 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];

  gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.10], (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50], (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50], (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

  [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];                        

  [super setBackgroundView:backgroundView]; }
```

Comment: not following??? why not just `#define` your own constant?

Comment: When applying UITableViewStyleGrouped to a UITableViewCell it adds a cornerRadius. This corner radius appears to either 8,9, or 10. I'd prefer to use the same cornerRadius which this style applies and not use my own guess. I assume that this is a constant somewhere?